# テキストを選択し右クリックでコピーを選んだときにクリップボードにコピーさせない方法

Tags: javascript

右クリックを禁止にしてテキストをコピーさせないようにしてるサイトはよくみるのですが、
Firefoxの`Shift+右クリック`で禁止を迂回して右クリックメニューから`コピー`を選択してもコピーできないサイトに出くわしました。

javascriptで何らかの阻害措置をとってると思うのですが、どのような方法を取ればこのような動作になるのでしょうか？

見つけたのはこちらのサイトになります。
http://www.lyric.in.th/lyric.php?n=11454

(テキストのコピー自体はソースコードからできました。)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そのサイトのソースコード24行目に阻害措置が書かれています.
著作権発生しないレベルのコードだと思いますが念の為転載はしません.
内部的にはClipboard API [copy - Web 技術のリファレンス | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Reference/Events/copy) を使ってデフォルトのコピー動作を`preventDefault`で阻害しています.